# Filling dependence on order of points in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 FillingStyle -> LightGray, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Results in no filling, whereas...

```
ListPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0.5}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 FillingStyle -> LightGray, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

gives the expected fill.

Why does the order matter or more literally is this expected behavior and if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the data

```
ListPlot[Sort /@
  {{{1, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 FillingStyle -> LightGray,
 Joined -> True,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: That certainly works but don't you think its a bit odd it doesn't work without the Sort?

Comment: Sort is required because Mma does not know whether you intend the data to be ordered. For example, How would the following be filled? `ListPlot[{{{1, 0}, {0, 0.5}, {.5, .75}}, {{1, 1}, {2, .25}, {0, 1}}}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True]`

Comment: I agree your example is ambiguous but mine is not, interpolation between their points in x is not multivalued and the space between the lines is well defined.

Comment: Presumably the only prior analysis done is to check whether the data is ordered. Your data isn't. `OrderedQ /@ {{{1, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}}` gives `{False, False}`.

Comment: Fair point.  I guess I'm assuming that internally some kind of interpolation function is being built and the intersection of support for both objects is constructed.  My assumption is most likely wrong because of the counter-cases, like yours, where its not obvious what to do.  I'll accept your answer.